# Using SignalR on non-web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

I would like to implement SignalR into one of my WPF applications for its real-time capabilities to communicate between client and server. However, everything I have read points to SignalR only being used on web browsers. Would it be possible to use SignalR in my application that does not include any web browsers (without adding a WebBrowser element to my project displays)? To try to clarify, I would like to use all the perks of SignalR such that a couple displays in my application update their data in real time, with no web browsers. If so, what would this look like? Thanks!

Comment: It is sure possible, I did it with console apps so it is definitely possible. See my [repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-SignalR)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create a real time chat application in WPF without SignalR?

Comment: Sure, you could always use a [WCF duplex service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services)

Comment: appreciate your quick help here. thanks.

Comment: You can also use pure websockets, I wrote real time chat application for WPF\android\ios\web with websockets.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, SignalR has [.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/), [Java](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client), and [JavaScript](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS/) clients. A web browser isn't necessary. Technically anything that knows one of the transport protocols that SignalR provides (such as web sockets) could have a client written for it.